# Flickity carousel: Wrap prev and next buttons inside a custom div

Tags: javascript, flickity

I'm working with flickity carousel, and I want to warp next and prev buttons inside some custom div.

By default, flickity creates the buttons dinamically as direct children of the .main-carousel div/section.

This is the code i'm getting running flickity js:

````
<section class="main-carousel>
   <div class="flickity-viewport">...</div>
   <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button previous"></button>
   <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button next"></button>
</section>```

And this is what i want to get:

<section class="main-carousel>
    <div class="flickity-viewport">...</div>
    <div class="my-div">
        <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button previous"></button>
        <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button next"></button>
    </div>
</section>
````

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery.

```
// first make sure the plugin has generated the html
$(document).ready(function(){

    // select the buttons
    buttons = $('.main-carousel .flickity-button')

    // add them to a newly created div
    new_div = $('<div class="my-div"></div>').append(buttons)

    // append the new div (my-div) to .main-carousel
    $('.main-carousel').append(new_div)
})
```

You might also need to add the missing " in `<section class="main-carousel>`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in vanilla js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div')
   buttonWrapper.setAttribute("class", "my-div")

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem.querySelectorAll('.flickity-button'), (item) => {
      buttonWrapper.appendChild(item)
   })
   elem.appendChild(buttonWrapper)

})
```

Where `elem` is your `document.querySelector('.main-carousel')`.